# How to add text in a textarea and post it to the service

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my Link by which my div is visible:

```
<a href="javascript:addMethod()">+ Create a new comment</a>
```

and method that is called on it is as follows:

```
function addMethod() 
{       
 try {           
var div = document.getElementById('addComments');         
div.style.visibility = "visible";           
var textArea = document.getElementById('Textarea1');            
textArea.style.visibility = "visible";            
var mashupId = _settings.ratedObjectId;            
var tenantId = _settings.tenantId;            
var comments = null;            
var user = { "Id": 2007, 
"FirstName": "Ufone",
 "LastName": "", 
"EmailAddress": "ahmed.ali@vidizmo.com509" };            
var ratingInfo = {                
"Id": 0,                
"TenantId": tenantId,               
 "UserId": user.Id,               
 "FirstName": user.FirstName,                
"LastName": user.LastName,                
"Rating": 0,               
 "EmailAddress": user.EmailAddress,                
"Comments": comments,               
 "RatedObjectTypeInfo": { "Id": 2 },                
"RatingTypeInfo": { "Id": 1 },                
"MashupRatingInfo": { "MashupMetaInfoId": mashupId },                
"RatedObjectId": mashupId,                
"TotalCount": 0            
};    
var url = "http://services.farooq.tv/RatingInfoManagementService/RatingInfoManagementService.svc/ajax/AddRating";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(ratingInfo),
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (d) 
{                   
 if (d.comments == true){      
console.log(d);                    
alert("Success");    
},
            
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                
console.log(xhr);
            }            
});

}

catch (err) 
{
alert(err);
}
}
```

This is my div and inside it is a text area and buttons.

```
 <div id="addComments" align="center" style="width:300px; height:300px; visibility:hidden">
       <textarea  id="Textarea1" style="width:300px; height:300px; visibility:hidden">  </textarea>
   <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    
    </div>
```

I want to add text in a text area and save it in a variable after submit button is pressed

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

and the variable in which I want to store the text of a text area is

```
var comments = null;
```

Please help; I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/erANK/

You could set the textArea with this line

```
 var comments = textArea.value = 'This is added text';
```